# jQuery selector не выделяют полностью. Пропускает элементы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть HTML таблица, которую надо обновлять с помощью ajax:

```
<table id="types_table" border="1">

    <tr>
        <td><h5>Ship type:</h5></td>
        <td><h5>Count left:</h5></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="types_row" data-type="1">
        <td>1</td>
        <td id="count_td">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="types_row" data-type="2">
        <td>2</td>
        <td id="count_td">3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="types_row" data-type="3">
        <td>3</td>
        <td id="count_td">2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="types_row" data-type="4">
        <td>4</td>
        <td id="count_td">1</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

JS кусок выглядит так:

```
var types = data.types_key;
console.log(types); //json объект в порядке полном.

for (var key in types) {
    console.log("type: "+key+" count: "+$(" tr#types_row[data-type=" + key + "] td#count_td").text());
}
```

От сервера приходит совершенно нормальный json объект `{1=4,2=3,3=2,4=1};`
Но применить этот объект к таблице я не могу - т.к. селекторы выделяют неизвестно что.

```
type: 1 count: 4
type: 2 count: 
type: 3 count: 
type: 4 count:
```

это то, что написала мне консоль. Почему селектор сработал только для одного элемента?  Таблица ведь имеет эти аттрибуты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Селектор jQuery по ID элемента возвращает первый встретившийся элемент. Соответственно у тебя находится первый `<tr>`, а потом он же фильтруется по `data-type`.

Для того, чтобы твой код заработал, надо у всех `<tr>` выставить класс `types_row` и его использовать в селекторе, тогда код будет работать так как ты хочешь.

Comment: Хочу уточнить: должен ли ID в html документе быть уникальным?

Comment: По хорошему должен, но если он будет не уникальным, ничего очень критичного не случится. Все известные мне браузеры нормально отображают страницы.

Comment: ID ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО должен быть уникальным! см. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 : id = name [CS]
This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document., иначе будете всегда в js с этим багом маяться